# Prove that $2a\ln\left(x_2-x_1+\frac{e}{a}\right)+1<0$

Tags: calculus

> Denote $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}+a\ln x(a \in \mathbb{R}).$ If there exist two zero-point $x_1，x_2(x_1<x_2)$ for $f(x)$, prove $2a\ln\left(x_2-x_1+\frac{e}{a}\right)+1<0.$

I have obtain that

- $0<x_2-x_1<1$,
- $a>2e$,

but based on theses above, we can merely have

\begin{align} 2a\ln\left(x_2-x_1+\frac{e}{a}\right)+1<2a\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\leq  2a\cdot1/2+1=a+1. \end{align}

Comment: @TheSimpliFire yes,they are both the roots for $f(x)=0$.